# Complex analysis notation conventions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose you've got functions $z:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},U:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. How would you interpret computing $\frac{d}{dt}U(z(t))$? Supposing that $m,n:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are the component functions for $z$, the regular multivariable chain rule would give $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}(z(t))\frac{d}{dt}m(t) + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}(z(t))\frac{d}{dt}n(t)$. The reason I'm asking is because I recently calculated, using the function $z:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $z'(t)$ to be $\frac{d}{dt}cos(t)+i\frac{d}{dt}sin(t)=-sin(t)+i cos(t) = i(cos(t)+i sin(t)) = i e^{it}$, which looks correct, but isn't consistent with the use of the regular(real) chain rule above. Details would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are your functions $z$ and $U$ in this context?